# Letting the operating system know when the cursor is in a JavaFX TextBox

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am writing a Java application that will run on a tablet with Windows 7 installed. The user interacts with the device via a stylus and an on-screen keyboard provided by the operating system. In applications with *native* text boxes, the on-screen keyboard automatically appears when the cursor enters a text box and disappears when the cursor leaves. This is very desirable behavior.

Unfortunately, the operating system is not aware of JavaFX's text boxes. Therefore, the on-screen keyboard does not automatically appear when the cursor enters a text box in my application. The user is forced to manually drag the on-screen keyboard from the edge of the screen into view.

Is there a way to retain this behavior of *native* text boxes in JavaFX 2.0?